# Android Studio How to get session cookies that i requested by post method using Volley

Tags: android-studio, web

I want to make when i login with id and password in my application which is my univ website account, then application show my profile in the university.
And I don't want to use WebView, but Volley(i want get session cookie).

So what I want to know is how it works exactly. because I tried with Volley but, it brings JSESSION etc not login session.

And it is my LoginActivity.java code that I tried. Ignore Log.d().

```
   package com.tistory.hyomyo.kangnamuniversityapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.NetworkResponse;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String TAG = "LoginActivityTag";

    private TextInputEditText textId;
    private TextInputEditText textPassword;
    private Button sendBtn;
    private RequestQueue queue;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        textId = findViewById(R.id.login_uid);
        textPassword = findViewById(R.id.login_password);
        sendBtn = findViewById(R.id.send_btn);

        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url = "https://knusso.kangnam.ac.kr/sso/pmi-sso-login-uid-password.jsp";

        final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d("Response", response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                if(error.networkResponse.statusCode == 302){
                    Log.d("ErrorResponse",error.networkResponse.allHeaders.toString());
                    final String url1 = error.networkResponse.headers.get("Location");
                    String str = error.networkResponse.headers.get("Set-Cookie");
                    //str = str.substring(str.indexOf("JSESSIONID="),str.indexOf("JSESSIONID=")+"JSESSIONID".length()+32);
                    NetworkResponse networkResponse = requestUrl(url1, str, "TAG", 0);
                    if(networkResponse!=null)
                        Log.d("networkResponse", networkResponse.headers.toString());
                    else
                        Log.d("networkResponse", "null");
                }else if(error.networkResponse.statusCode == 500){
                    Log.e("WrongPassword","Wrong password Error or Something is wrong: 500");
                }
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                // 나중에 예외처리 구현 권장
                params.put("gid","gid_web");
                params.put("returl", "https://web.kangnam.ac.kr/sso/index.jsp");
                params.put("uid", textId.getText().toString());
                params.put("password", textPassword.getText().toString());
                return params;
            }

            @Override
            protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {

                Log.i("response",response.headers.toString());
                Map<String, String> responseHeaders = response.headers;
                String rawCookies = responseHeaders.get("Set-Cookie");
                Log.i("cookies",rawCookies);
                return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
            }
        };

        stringRequest.setTag(TAG);

        sendBtn.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            queue.add(stringRequest);
        });

    }

    private NetworkResponse requestUrl(final String url, final String Cookie, String tag, int i){
        final NetworkResponse[] ret = {null};
        Log.d("요청유알엘", url);
        final StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, response -> {
            Log.d("응답하라", url);
        }, error -> {
            Log.d("URL", url);
            Log.d("Cookie", Cookie);
            Log.d("ERROR", error.toString());
            if(error.
                    networkResponse.
                    statusCode == 302){
                final String url2 = error.networkResponse.headers.get("Location");

                ret[0] = requestUrl(url2, Cookie, tag+i, i+1);
            }else{
                Log.d("Other Error Code", error.networkResponse.statusCode+"");
                ret[0] = error.networkResponse;
            }
        }){
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("Cookie", Cookie);
                return params;
            }

            @Override
            protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                if (response == null) {
                    Log.d("응답됨", "null");
                    super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
                }Log.d("응답됨", response.headers.get("Set-Cookie"));
                ret[0] = response;

                return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
            }
        };
        request.setTag(tag);
        queue.add(request);

        return ret[0];
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if(queue!=null){
            queue.cancelAll(TAG);
            queue.cancelAll("TAG");
            queue.cancelAll("TAG0");
            queue.cancelAll("TAG1");
            queue.cancelAll("TAG2");
            queue.cancelAll("TAG3");
        }
    }

    public void logLargeString(String str){
        if(str.length() > 3000){
            Log.i(TAG, str.substring(0, 3000));
            logLargeString(str.substring(3000));
        }else{
            Log.i(TAG, str);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show what you have already tried. Give more details.

Comment: ok i edit my question now